# Working around nasty Pattern Matcher bug

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

I am defining a generic tree structure, i.e. one which can be extended so that for example branches and leaves contain additional values (I need this to add a name string for example).

So it looks like this:

```
trait TreeNodes {
  val Node              = Either
  type Node[+B, +L]     = Either[B, L]
  val IsBranch          = Left
  type IsBranch[+B, +L] = Left[B, L]
  val IsLeaf            = Right
  type IsLeaf[+B, +L]   = Right[B, L]
}

object TreeLike extends TreeNodes {
  trait BranchLike[Elem, B, L] {
    type N = Node[B, L]

    def iterator: Iterator[N]
  }

  trait LeafLike[Elem] {
    def value: Elem
  }
}
trait TreeLike[Elem, Repr] {
  type Leaf   <: TreeLike.LeafLike[Elem]
  type Branch <: TreeLike.BranchLike[Elem, Branch, Leaf]

  def root: Branch
}
```

Unfortunately, there is a pattern matcher bug:

```
def test[Elem, T <: TreeLike[Elem, T]](tree: T): Unit = {
  import TreeLike.{IsLeaf, IsBranch}

  def printLeaves(b: T#Branch): Unit = b.iterator.foreach {
    case IsLeaf(l)    => println(l.value)
    case IsBranch(c)  => printLeaves(c)
  }

  printLeaves(tree.root)
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
[error]         during phase: patmat
[error]      library version: version 2.10.3
[error]     compiler version: version 2.10.3
...
[error]    symbol definition: case val x1: b.N
[error]                  tpe: b.N
[error]        symbol owners: value x1
[error]       context owners: value x0$1 -> value $anonfun -> method printLeaves -> 
  method test -> object Voodoo -> package typerbug
...
[error] no-symbol does not have an owner
```

I suspect patmat has troubles with `T#Branch` somehow. Any ideas how to work around here?

I am also not 100% happy with wrapping leaves and branches in `Either`. This was necessary because the stuff got way out of hand when I tried to define a super type of `LeafLike` and `BranchLike` and figuring out how to correctly sub type that in implementations, and pattern matching broke done as well because I didn't figure out how to get correct extractors. So perhaps using `Either` is not that as a bad idea?

Comment: The compiler doesn't crash when using Scala 2.11.0-M6...

Comment: I think you're seeing [SI-7891](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7891) and there is a long list of bugs with that message. :/

Comment: @S.R.I interesting... That ticket doesn't say it is solved in 2.11.0-M6, though. I should perhaps attach my example there.

Comment: Yes, this error seems to be hitting the compiler all over and it's a swampland of too-many-scenarios. Just search for "no-symbol does not have an owner" to see how many feet have trodden that path. [search-link](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3501?jql=text%20~%20%22no-symbol%20does%20not%20have%20an%20owner%22) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type alias `N` is a "problem" (WTF).

```
  trait BranchLike[Elem, B, L] {
    def iterator: Iterator[Node[B, L]]
  }
```

This makes it compile. Only that I am not very motivated to continue building this structure if it's about to collapse :-(